# Updating in a REQUIRES_NEW then finding in a different transaction returns old data. Why?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee, second-level-cache

This question is best described by a picture I think.  I hope someone can help me.  Thanks[image]

Comment: Are you sure this question is about the second level cache? I personally don't think it is. Did you actually provide all the details? Are (1) and (2) performed inside a single method of EJB1?

Comment: yes 1 and 2 are performed inside a single method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Pascal, if the two calls from EJB1 are in the same transaction then it's clear that (2) cannot see the changes performed by (1) because they were performed in another transaction (assuming a reasonable transaction isolation level, of course)

```
1. EJB1 transaction (TX1) starts
2.  EJB1.(1) called
3.   EJB2.update row started => TX1 is suspended and
     a new transaction, TX2, is started
4.   The update is performed
5.   TX2 commits
6.  TX1 is resumed - it can't see changes by TX2 because it's isolated from
    changes performed by other transactions during its "life"
7.  EJB1.(2) invokes EJB2.find row withing the context of TX1 => can't see TX2's changes
8. TX1 commits
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you gave all the context but if (1) and (2) are running inside the same transaction, I'd say that the entity is in the L1 cache, that's what the question suggests,  and that changes made in "*update row*" are not visible because they were done inside another persistence context (a nested transaction), hence the need to [`refresh`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) the state of the instance from the database.

Comment: so your theory is it's the first level cache that's returning the old object?

Comment: @tieTYT Yes and I'm pretty sure it's more than a theory :) (by the way, this question seems to be provider agnostic and there is no L2 cache in JPA 1.0).